# Use OS X spaces with SWT application

Tags: java, macos, swt

I'm new to OS X spaces. It's unclear to me whether they are window or application bound. Is it possible to read the current space of my application somehow using SWT and to set it again, so my application always opens on "its" space?

Answer (score 1):

`Shell.setFullScreen(true)` moves a shell to a separate full screen space. That is the only SWT that interacts with spaces / mission control.